# Why is $_POST["Name of Input"] not returning the value of the input?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Forenote: I am fairly new to php and HTML, so I apologize in advance if there are any blaring logical issues. Please feel free to point them out.

I currently have a feature on my HTML page involving a dropdown menu that contains the values 1 - 4. Upon choosing one of the numeric values, the corresponding number of textboxes "appear" below the dropdown menu. What is actually happening is that a division containing the proper amount of textboxes become unhidden when the numeric value is pressed.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#elementreg").on("change", function() {
      var val = $(this).val();

      $('.types').hide(); //hide all
      $(`#${val}`).show(); //show by matching the selected value
    });
  });
</script>

<label for="How Many Chips">How Many Chips?:</label>

<select class="medium" id="elementreg" name="amount">
  <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<div class="types" id="1">
  <input name="First Chip ID">
</div>

<div class="types" id="2">
  <input name="First Chip ID">
  <input name="Second Chip ID">
</div>

<div class="types" id="3">
  <input name="First Chip ID">
  <input name="Second Chip ID">
  <input name="Third Chip ID">
</div>

<div class="types" id="4">
  <input name="First Chip ID">
  <input name="Second Chip ID">
  <input name="Third Chip ID">
  <input name="Fourth Chip ID">
</div>
```

When I try to retrieve the value of any of the chip ID's and save it to a variable in PHP using the $_POST[""] function, the value of the variable comes out blank.

For example, when I utilize the following code to save the First Chip ID to a variable and write to a file, the file comes out blank.

```
$FirstChipID = $_POST["First Chip ID"];
```

Could someone explain to me why this type of behavior occurs? Is it because I am initializing the "First Chip ID" and other inputs multiple times? Any and all help in recognizing and going around this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: I don’t see a form post

Comment: _"Is it because I am initializing the "First Chip ID" and other inputs multiple times?"_ - Most likely yes. Even if they are in a hidden div, they will still be submitted. Instead of repeating the inputs, just have them once and hide/show them instead as needed. To allow multiple inputs with the same name (all will still be submitted though), then you can use the `[]` syntax: `name="foo[]"`. Then `$_POST['foo']` will be an array with each input value.

Comment: @DanielA.White The script shown is a snippet of the body of the html, including the form.

Comment: @M.Eriksson Would you have any advice on how I could approach hiding/show as needed by modifying the script?

Comment: I don’t see a form tag

Comment: "Unless explicitly specified, the default method is 'get'." In other words, you don't even have a form element, and the default is "get", so $_POST will be empty because you haven't actually used it. You can always use PHP's [`$_REQUEST`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) method which captures both types

Answer (score 0):

First of all it would be a good idea use values for both `id` and `name` attributes without spaces. At least for JavaScript it makes is easier to refer to an element.

It is OK to use the same name for input elements. If you use `<fieldset>` elements in your form it has some build-in features that you can use. If a fieldset is disabled the child input elements will not be submitted. So, disable all fieldsets as a stating point and enable one of them depending on what is selected in the `amount`. To hide the fieldsets that are disabled you can use CSS.

I added an event listener for the submit event, so that you can see what data will be submitted. You can use the PHP function `print_r($_POST)` to see alle the post data in the request.

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('change', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  switch(e.target.name){
    case 'amount':
      // disable all fieldsets
      form.querySelectorAll('fieldset').forEach(fs => fs.disabled = true);
      // enable the right fieldset
      form[`type_${e.target.value}`].disabled = false;
      break;
  }
});

// event listener is just for testing
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let data = new FormData(e.target);
  console.log([...data]);
});
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

fieldset[disabled] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form name="form01" method="POST">
  <label for="How Many Chips">
    <span>How Many Chips?:</span>
    <select class="medium" id="elementreg" name="amount" required>
      <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <fieldset name="type_1" disabled>
    <input name="chip_1" type="text" required>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset name="type_2" disabled>
    <input name="chip_1" type="text" required>
    <input name="chip_2" type="text" required>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset name="type_3" disabled>
    <input name="chip_1" type="text" required>
    <input name="chip_2" type="text" required>
    <input name="chip_3" type="text" required>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset name="type_4" disabled>
    <input name="chip_1" type="text" required>
    <input name="chip_2" type="text" required>
    <input name="chip_3" type="text" required>
    <input name="chip_4" type="text" required>
  </fieldset>
  <label>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </label>
</form>
```